# How to send MTOM enabled soap request to java webservice

Tags: c#, mtom

I need to send xml/MTOM documents to a java webservice that is MTOM enabled. I've searched everywhere for an example but none seem to fit my criteria.

In SoapUI I can specify an attachment, reference it within an XML body and send it to the Java. i.e. cid:62488378367 and the actual attachment is an MTOM binary attachment which appears at the bottom:

------=_Part_1_32419823.1433348130037
Content-Type: image/tiff
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <62488378367>
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="Output.tif"

How do I replicate this document in C# to send as a SOAP request? Just looking for a minimal example.

Thanks.

Comment: Ever found an solution? I'm looking for the same thing but it's hard to find an understandeble example.. :(